# Offline marine navigation software

Tags: offline, maps, dark-theme

Is there a good and affordable marine navigation software for OS X or Windows that includes charts? Offline usage is a must, as there's no reliable internet connection after leaving coast.

Mandatory features include

- Shows water depth, sea markers (buoys etc.). "The usual stuff"
- Shows current location on the map, based on GPS. Preferably works with any NMEA device, but requiring specific (cheap, say, <50€) GPS is okay too.
- Shows speed and course
- High-quality charts for Europe (other parts of the world are obviously a plus). [OpenSeaMap](http://www.openseamap.org/index.php?id=openseamap&L=1) is rather incomplete.
- Price including charts less than 200€

Optional things - "nice to have":

- Night colors mode - during night, having dark theme (in addition to adjusting brightness of the display) is really useful for preserving night vision.
- Recording tracks and showing recorded tracks
- Custom markers - adding markers to locations with custom description.
- [AIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Identification_System) support (shows other boats on the map)
- [GRIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) support (weather information)

---

Here's an example of good map view (without boat location): it includes stones, land, depths, buoys, lighthouses (with sector colors), underwater pipes etc.

[image: Example map]

---

[OpenCPN](http://opencpn.org/) is free with good feature set. Unfortunately, marine charts for European countries are usually crazy expensive - for Finland's coast, a full set of OpenCPN compatible electronic charts costs approximately 1000€ ($1351.40). That isn't too much for professional usage, but for private use, it's pretty steep.

For Android, there's [Navionics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.navionics.singleAppEurope), which is affordable (35€/$47.31) and includes charts for whole Europe (different edition for Northern America).

Answer (score 2):

French navigators use to consider [MaxSea](http://www.maxsea.com) as the leader in this domain. Obvioulsy, their softwares are not free, but at least they allow offline navigation (they're used on round-the-world races).

I must admit I've never used it myself, but I've only seen good reviews about these products.

Typically, starting offers like [MaxSea TimeZero Navigator](http://www.maxsea.com/products/software/timezero_navigator) (price 499 €) will include

> GPS positioning
>
> Marine weather forecast service
>
> Free worldwide tide database
>
> Management of Routes and Waypoints
>
> North America Tidal Current with ETA calculation (only available for the US market)

Concerning specific marine charts, they stand that

> MaxSea Time Zero Navigator Wide package includes the marine software navigation MaxSea TimeZero Navigator and a chart area to be selected from a wide variety of electronic marine charts.
>
> In the US, MaxSea TimeZero Navigator includes free NOAA US raster and vector high resolution charts covering the entire US Coast, including Alaska, Hawaii, Pacific Islands and Great Lakes.

I guess you should give them a call to have a better view on what charts are offered for your navigation in Finland ...

Comment: @Olli I will leave my recommandation to use MaxSea, even if price tag is not in your expected range, oonly a s a possible solution (disclaimer : I do not work for MaxSea :-)). I however do understand it won't be the best fitting recommandation.